# If $f$ is continuous and $X$ is compact, then $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is bounded

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

If $f$ is continuous and $X$ is compact, then $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is bounded.

I know this has probably been doing 9001 times, but I couldn't find it for arbitrary metric spaces, and also wanted to get my proof verified.

$proof:$

Let $p$ be the metric in $Y$.

Assume the hypothesis. Let $F: X \rightarrow Y \times Y$ be defined by $F(x)=(f(x),y)$ for some fixed $y \in Y$. We must show that there is some $y \in Y$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $p(f(x),y) \leq n$, $\forall x \in X$.

Then $pF$ is a continuous function with a compact domain, $X$, and so it achieves its maximum value, at say, $x_0$. Let $pF(x_0)=n$

Thus $p(f(x),y) \leq p(f(x_0),y)=n$.

Thus $f$ is bounded on $X$.

Comment: What is a compact map?

Comment: oops, meant bounded.

Comment: The image of $f$ is compact, so bounded.

Comment: even for general top spaces?

Comment: The space $Y$ is a *metric* space, and every compact subset of a metric space is bounded.

Comment: Right. Can you tell me if my proof is logically coherent anyway?

Comment: I believe you need to fix $y=y_0 \in Y$ for it to make sense, but otherwise it looks ok.

Comment: Actually, I missed the fact your $y$ is fixed.  The only problem I see is that "We must show that there is some $y\in Y$ and $n\in \mathbb{N}$ [...]" is an awkward statement, since the symbol $y$ is already fixed.

Also, the metric takes values in the real numbers, right?  Therefore, your upper bound won't necessarily be an integer.  

Just change that to "We must show there is some $n\in\mathbb{R}$ [...]".

Comment: Define what bounded function is.